# Effectiveness of Dashboard in relation to time on site

Tags: usability, interaction-design, dashboard

Is there any research/insight to dashboard effectiveness? In my personal experience I do not spend lot of time reading through different content on the website. Lot of things depends on the dynamic content and keeping things simple instead of adding widgets. I'm curious if there is any research done in the context of users spend less and less time on a site

Comment: Hi Baski, welcome to the UX exchange. In regards to your question I would rephrase it a bit to see if there is any research to support time on site in relationship to dashboard usage. As is stands, your questioned is skewed towards a negative impact, which could eliminate positive results.

Comment: Thanks Johnny and agree. Will look at how to rephrase better. I'm trying to see if it's still relevant to provide big dashboard in the era of flat design/mobile. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an interesting article written by the Nielson Norman group which discusses the time spent reading which suggests a need for more relevant and appropriate information to retain attention. Whilst not directly appropriate to your question does back up your own experience.

[Nielson Norman Group Article - How little do users read?](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/how-little-do-users-read/)

Research is thin on the ground at present for dashboard effectiveness, it seems more prevalent to find snippets of this in research papers:

[A PDF download - Marketing Dashboards Paper - Mentions Effectiveness](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/236745039_Dashboards__Marketing_Why_What_How_and_Which_Research_is_Needed/file/3deec526a1f3828a31.pdf)

Overall from experience the way information is presented is wholly dependent on the user and what message you are trying to convey. For example, I have lots of complicated sales figures, traffic etc. and I need to display this to people who will not have long to read it - I use a dashboard. I can show them top line information instantly that they can then use on a conference call. If they have more time they could view a table which goes into a more granular detail.

If you haven't already take a look at Google Scholar - there are a few results which come up when you search for dashboard effectiveness but these are only small sections of the entire paper.

[Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.co.uk/)

One last important thing to note is that dashboards are going to be there to summarise and give us a top line view of information. Where is the insight? It is difficult to communicate insight in data as a part of a dashboard, which introduces a problem. As an analyst I can look at a dashboard and tell you insight instantly, this is because I know the data. The CEO opens the dashboard and sees "We have 100 users today, we only had 50 yesterday, we are improving" - when infact yesterday was a weekend and that is when we see lower traffic. It is easy to infer incorrect assumptions by looking at an overview, sometimes we need a bit more detail to really understand information.